# Mapbox getCanvas().toDataURL() not rendering markers

Tags: javascript, image, canvas, mapbox

I'm trying to obtain a picture of a map using Mapbox. This should be very simple using
`map.getCanvas().toDataURL();` The catch is that I have [markers](https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/example/add-a-marker/) on my map and these are not present when I obtain the image using the method mentioned above.

This is an example of what I'm experiencing: https://codepen.io/loskiorama/pen/YzeeMqm

Is there any way I could get a "screenshot" of my map that includes the markers?
I'm bundling this on a single js file so I can't use solutions like [html2canvas](https://html2canvas.hertzen.com/) as I'd like to keep my file as small as possible.

Thanks!